# "What" = "the thing" in the beginning of the sentence

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-starts

Is the sentence

> What he didn't know is that in the future (...)

correct?
The meaning should be similar to "The thing that he didn't know..."

Comment: _What he didn't know was that in the future..._ Proofreading is off topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the same as saying "The thing he did not know was..."

You should probably change your sentence from "is that" to "was that" so that it is all in the same tense though. ie: what he *does* not know *is*, or what he *did* not know *was*.